# Delete trigger is not firing

Tags: apex, trigger, delete

Below is the trigger on ContentVersion object. Namely, there is a custom object, Art Inventory, that can have a file (i.e. pics of art) associated with its record. So I am updating a field in the custom object with the ID from ContentVersion when new file is inserted, so I can display it in large window in the Art record details. The trigger works fine when I am inserting new file, however it does not fire when I am deleting the file from the record, i.e. a picture from the ContentVersion object. I have checked in the database, and the record is deleted from the object, but I have no idea why it is not firing the trigger. Do I need to check in ContentDocument object? Below is the code:

```
trigger tr_new_file_insert_for_art_inventory on ContentVersion (after insert, after update, before delete, after delete) 
{
    Set<Id> art_Ids = new Set<Id>();
    String cv_Id;
    String cd_id;
        
    if(trigger.isDelete)
    {
        System.debug('It is Delete trigger');
        
        for(ContentVersion cv_d : trigger.old)
        {
            art_ids.add(cv_d.FirstPublishLocationId);
            cv_id = cv_d.id;
            cd_id = cv_d.ContentDocumentId;
        }
        
        List<art_inventory_data__c> a_deleted = 
            [
                SELECT  Id, file_ID__c
                FROM    art_inventory_data__c 
                WHERE   Id IN:art_ids 
                AND file_ID__c=:cv_id
            ];
        
        Integer a_deleted_size = a_deleted.size();
        Integer files_size_deleted = art_ids.size();
        
        System.debug('A_deleted_size = ' + a_deleted_size + '; File_deleted_size = ' + files_size_deleted);
        
        if(files_size_deleted > 0 && a_deleted_size > 0)
        {
            for(art_inventory_data__c p:a_deleted)                        
            {
                p.file_ID__c =  null;
                update a_deleted;
                System.debug('Updated!');
            }
        }
    }   
    
    if(trigger.isInsert)
    {
        System.debug('It is Insert trigger');
        
        for(ContentVersion cv : trigger.new)
            {
                art_ids.add(cv.FirstPublishLocationId);
                cv_id = cv.id;
            }
        
        //System.debug('New FirstPublishLocationId = ' + art_ids);
        
        Integer files_size = art_ids.size();
        
        if(files_size > 0)
        {
            // get those records from art_inventory_data__c object that have their file Id's record in ContentVersion
            List<art_inventory_data__c> a = 
                        [
                            SELECT  Id 
                            FROM    art_inventory_data__c 
                            WHERE   Id IN:art_ids
                        ];
            
            Integer a_size = a.size();
            
            if(a_size > 0)
                {
                    //System.debug('New Content Version Id = ' + cv_id);
                    
                    for(art_inventory_data__c p:a)
                    {
                        p.file_ID__c = cv_id;
                        update a;
                    }
                }
        else
            {
                for(ContentVersion cv : trigger.new)
                {
                    cd_id = cv.ContentDocumentId;
                }
                
                //System.debug('New ContentDocumentId = ' + cd_id);
                
                // first get the record from ContentVersion object that have its FirstPublishLocationId
                List< ContentVersion > c = 
                            [
                                SELECT  FirstPublishLocationId 
                                FROM    ContentVersion 
                                WHERE   ContentDocumentId =:cd_id
                                    AND FirstPublishLocationId != null
                            ];
                
                for(ContentVersion c_f:c)
                    {
                        art_ids.add(c_f.FirstPublishLocationId);
                    }
                    
                //System.debug('Old FirstPublishLocationId = ' + art_ids);
                    
                List< ContentVersion > c_updated = 
                            [
                                SELECT  Id 
                                FROM    ContentVersion 
                                WHERE   ContentDocumentId =:cd_id
                                ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC LIMIT 1
                            ];
                            
                for(ContentVersion c_u:c_updated)
                    {
                        cv_id = c_u.Id;
                    }
                
                //System.debug('New Content Version Id = ' + cv_id);
                
                List<art_inventory_data__c> a_updated = 
                            [
                                SELECT  Id, file_ID__c
                                FROM    art_inventory_data__c 
                                WHERE   Id IN:art_ids
                            ];
                   
                Integer a_updated_size = a_updated.size();
                Integer files_size_updated = art_ids.size();
                
                //System.debug('A_updated_size = ' + a_updated_size + '; File_size = ' + files_size_updated);
                
                if(files_size_updated > 0 && a_updated_size > 0)
                {
                    System.debug('cv_id = ' + cv_id);
                    
                    for(art_inventory_data__c p:a_updated)
                    {
                        p.file_ID__c = cv_id;
                        update a_updated;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe what you may want is a trigger on `ContentDocument` for deletions. If you're deleting the File outright, you're deleting the ContentDocument and the versions will go with it.

Comment: Yup, you are right, as I also suspected, I just checked and created new trigger on ContentDocument. Thanks